# How to pass a string as an argument in Handlebars helper expression?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to create my own Handlebars helper, but am having problems passing it arguments. For context, I'm trying to hack Ghost (http://tryghost.org), but I suspect this is a more general Handlebars problem.

### Working

First, a working example. Here is the relevant part of my template:

```
<h1>{{myHelper}}</h1>
```

Here is my `Handlebars.registerHelper` method (Ghost renames it but it's the same):

```
ghost.registerThemeHelper("myHelper", function() { 
    console.log(this.posts[0].title); // outputs "Welcome to Ghost" to console
    return this.posts[0].title; // returns "Welcome to Ghost"
})
```

### Not Working

Below is what I want to achieve. The template:

```
<h1>{{myHelper "title"}}</h1> 
<h3>{{myHelper "slug"}}</h3>
```

When I try to pass arguments to the method it fails to substitute the variable:

```
ghost.registerThemeHelper("myHelper", function(myData) { 
    console.log(this.posts[0].myData); // outputs "undefined" to console
    return this.posts[0].myData; // returns nothing
})
```

What is the proper means of passing a string like "title" in order for it to be evaluated in an expression?

For any curious Ghost users, I registered my own helper within the `activateTheme()` function in `ghost/core/server.js`

Comment: Your problem is specific to Ghost, passing double quoted strings to Handlebars helpers works in the obvious manner. Have you tried looking at `console.log(arguments)` inside your helper to see what is really being passed in?

Comment: Here is the result of console.log(arguments): `{ '0': 'title', '1': { hash: {}, data: { blog: [Object] } } }`. The first argument, 0, is indeed 'title'.

Comment: So why are you looking at `this` then? Why not look at the `myData` argument?

Comment: sorry, as you can tell I'm new to javascript and am confused. I need `this` in order to access the child property of `posts`.

Comment: But you want to get the helper's parameter out of the `myData` argument, not from something inside `this`.

Comment: what I want is to output "Welcome to Ghost", and to do that I thought I needed the value of `this` and `myData`

Comment: But the `myData` argument isn't the same as `this.posts[0].myData`. You're probably looking for something closer to `this.posts[0][myData]` but I don't know anything about Ghost and I don't have an example to play with so I can't be more specific.

Comment: oh my God, that's the answer! Thank you thank you thank you. Please add it as an answer so I can upvote. So I'm still confused why that's the case, because `console.log(this.posts[0])` shows this:
`{ id: 2,
  uuid: '0965abbe-82b2-4b37-84d9-dc19474646cf',
  title: 'Welcome to Ghost',
  slug: 'welcome-to-ghost',`
  etc... That looks like an object, not an array to me. Why should the square brackets be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console.log` output for [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
{ '0': 'title', '1': { hash: {}, data: { blog: [Object] } } }
```

suggests that the first argument to the helper is `'title'` when you say `{{myHelper "title"}}`. If `this.posts[0]` is the post you're interested in, then you'd want to look at:

```
this.posts[0][myData]
```

to get the `title` property of `this.posts[0]` when `myData` is `'title'`. Note that square brackets are used to access both normal arrays (which are indexed by non-negative integers) and objects (which are indexed by strings).

A bit of time in the [MDN JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) reference might be helpful.